# Resizing the code section without break the Windows Executable

Tags: windows, assembly, operating-system, file-format

My project is the following: The program itself is a packer. It compress the original executable code, like UPX do it. . But I have a problem, PE header says that the physical size of the executable, is, for example, 80 bytes. But, the Windows explorer says that the program is smaller than that number. By this reason, the Windows Loader fails

I don't know how to change the PE header values about the size, to reflect properly the changes that my program made. I am looking for this topic inside the Microsoft Official Documentation, but I can't find it.

I can't show any source code because I don't know how to start.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you might get some help if you convince the SO audience that you are not writing a virus.

Comment: oK. @MarkLakata I am rewriting my post now.

Comment: Writing a packer is very complicated. You need to have a deep understanding of the PE file format and the Windows execution model. There's no reason to write your own packer. Just use UPX.

Comment: @RaymondChen But, The idea is learn more each day. If you just use a tool written by another person, you are losing the fun of understand how the tools works. I want to write my own packer and show it as a university project. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: It's great to learn new things. But one step at a time. First learn the PE format and the Windows execution model. You are trying to learn to drive by taking an F1 race car out on the road. You can start by writing a program that analyzes a PE file and prints all the information it can about it.

Comment: @RaymondChen Ok, I understand you, but, do you know where I can find a complete documentation about the PE format??? I have looking for Microsoft Documentation, but it is a shit. (Sorry for the last word). I have many hours surfing in the net, but I can't find a deep explaination about the PE format. Really I can't understand why there are few information about that format in the net.

Comment: Are you serious? https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=pe+format returns excellent articles about the PE format in the entire first page of hits. If you've spent hours searching for this and unable to find anything, you need to take an introductory course on using the Internet.

Comment: @CodyGray I have seen a lot of documents, but they don't explain how the PE filesize is calculated. I'm trying another solution: I'm trying to compress the .text section, and write the packer routine at the begin of the .text section, without change entry point and without add a new section. Thanks for your answer

Comment: The entry point tells the loader where to start executing. (See "PE format basics.") Just change the entry point and update the section size. You're making this a lot harder than it needs to be. (The fact that you don't want to change the entry point tells me you are trying to write a virus.) Packing saves disk space but at a significant performance cost. You lose demand-paging and code page sharing, both of which are bad news for multi-user systems, and the program will be harder to support in the field because crash dumps will be much more difficult to analyze.

Comment: @RaymondChen I am just writing a packer like UPX. If my packer is like a virus, can the AV software detect my packer as a malware??? If I find the solution to my problem, I will post it here.

Comment: Then just edit the entry point.

Comment: @RaymondChen I can't understand the documentation about how to add a section. I think that could be more easy just pack the code of the executable, and put the unpacker routine in the begin of the file. I am trying to do this because I don't know how to add a new section wihout break the Windows Executable.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Years ago I learned a lot about PE format and its sizes and stuff from source code of [Michael Tippach's Wuschel's DOS eXtender](http://tippach.business.t-online.de/wdosx/) especially from the **PE loader** part. It shows exactly how to read important information from the PE file, how to map import and export sections etc.

> **Diving guide:**
>   Search for `CreateProcess` points to `wdosx097.zip → SRC\WIN32\k32spawn.asm` and `wdosx097.zip → SRC\PE\loadpe.asm`

**2)** Another source code I have found useful for studying how processes and threads and TLS etc. look in memory was the **PE loader** from the [Wine project](https://www.winehq.org/) (sort of binary level compatible Windows emulator for Linux)

> **Diving guide:** Search for `CreateProcess` (http://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/?a=search&h=HEAD&st=commit&s=CreateProcess) points to http://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/dlls/kernel32/process.c

**3)** Another valuable source of the PE format might be the **PE loader** as implemented in the open source [ReactOS Project](https://www.reactos.org/) (Windows NT binary level compatible OS)

> **Diving guide:** This http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/reactos/dll/win32/kernel32/client/proc.c?view=markup file seems to deal with `CreateProcess`

All examples provide documentation of the PE format in the form of a code that reads it and uses it. It should give you more explanation (and some useful comments in the source code) in addition to the static documentation which should be easy to Google out nowadays (as suggested by @Cody-gray)

---

<sup>All 3 diving guides follow the same pattern. Search for implementation of Win32 function `CreateProcess` as this is the word which when pronounced causes OS to load the PE file and enliven it. The raw implementation may reside several source files far away e.g. in some kernel files where everyone trusts everyone all inhabitants strive for cleanliness, flawlesness and clear, straight and efficient streaming of thoughts is the common goal and all function names start with `Rtl..` and nobody remembers why..</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have started to read your links and they are very useful.

Comment: Can you give me a short explaination??? Because the ReactOS and Wine Source code are very big.

Comment: @jhonny6721 explanation of the code would not be short and might be well beyond my current understanding, but you can open new questions with particular things you're wondering about. To get you started I have added some starting points in the code bases where I would start sniffing around (see the **diving guide** in edited answer)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will start to learn your documentation.